# Does LG v30 record HDR video in manual mode

Tags: video, hdr

Does LG v30 record HDR video in manual mode or it's only in automatic mode ? Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the phone specification docs?

Comment: Yes, it records. Nothing about automatic/manual modes, which is the question about